# Finding Vuln in linux login console

Tags: authentication, linux, penetration-test, vulnerability

I'm trying to find vulnerability on an appliance based on Ubuntu 12.0.4
and this is about console (COM port) section now.

my findings:

1. The password field is sensitive to large string. for example if you input 100K byte string as password, the console will be stuck and after about 30 seconds return some ASCII code (100-200 bytes)
2. after a few times (5) incorrect password, it return grep help output (followed image)
   [image]

I want to let me know your comments or suggestion to find any issue on it (or maybe these findings are usual and i should look for other issue).

Comment: I think somehow the username,password is being used in grep input . Try to use `',",|` characters to break out of grep and execute commands.

Comment: I have tried some input but it was not any effect. also i tried (backtick)`sleep 30`(backtick) to check execution time but no change. :(

Comment: The grep should not be there. Its there means either its a decoy or its surely its the thing to break . Try combinations to break out of grep and  use eval

Comment: Perhaps the username or password is being stored in a variable... have you tried shellshock-ish inputs? `() { :;}; sleep 37;` or other variations.